# UNNEST/Flatten in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten, cross-join, unnest

I have a MySQL query that I want to convert into a snowflake.

MySQL query :

```
WITH t AS (
    select id,
        date,
        copt,
        split(copt, '|') [ 1 ] as "abc",
        split(copt, '|') [ 2 ] as "def",
        split(copt, '|') [ 3 ] as "xyz",
    from tablename
    where id in (
            123,
            456,
            789,
        )
        and date >= dateadd('day', -6, to_date('2021-12-17'))
        and date <= date '2021-12-17'
        and copt like '%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%|%'
)
SELECT t.id,
    t.date,
    catId,
    REPLACE(productId, '_', '') as productId,
FROM t
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        split(t."abc", '_'),
        split(t."def", '_'),
        split(t."xyz", '_'),
    ) as x(catId, productId, quantity)
where productid != ''
order by id
```

I have tried to replace `UNNEST()` with `FLATTEN()` but didn't succeed.

Can anyone help me out here to convert this query from MySQL to Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear the MySQL has UNNEST support, so I could not read the manual on that.

Also you have not provided any example input, and the output you are expecting, But assuming you `abc`, `def`, & `xzy` are arrays of independent sizes, and you are want all permutations the following SQL should work:

```
WITH cte_t(id,date, abc, def, xyz, productid) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, '2022-01-23'::date, 'a_b_c_d', 'd_e_f', 'x_y_w', 'not empty'),
    (2, '2022-01-23'::date, 'a_d', 'd_f', 'y_w', 'not empty'),
    (3, '2022-01-23'::date, 'a_c_d', 'f', 'y1_y2_w', 'not empty')
)
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.date,
    a.value AS catid,
    b.value AS productid,
    c.value AS quantity
FROM cte_t AS t
    ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.abc, '_') a
    ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.def, '_') b 
    ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.xyz, '_') c
WHERE productid != ''
```

gives:

| ID | DATE | CATID | PRODUCTID | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | d | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | d | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | d | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | e | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | e | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | e | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | e | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | f | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | d | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | d | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | d | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | e | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | e | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | e | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | e | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | f | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | d | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | d | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | d | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | e | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | e | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | e | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | e | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | f | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | w |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | w |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | y |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | d | d | y |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | y |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | y |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | w |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | d | d | w |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | w |
| 2 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | w |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | y1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | y1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | y1 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | y2 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | y2 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | y2 |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | a | f | w |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | w |
| 3 | 2022-01-23 | d | f | w |

Ok, that was more data the I was expecting, but there you go.

If how ever those three arrays are of the same size then you can use one [SPLIT_TO_TALBE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_to_table.html) and two [SPLIT_PART](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html):

```
WITH cte_t(id,date, abc, def, xyz, productid) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1, '2022-01-23'::date, 'a_b_c', 'd_e_f', 'x_y_w', 'not empty')
)
SELECT
    t.id,
    t.date,
    a.value AS catid,
    split_part(t.def, '_', a.index) AS productid,
    split_part(t.xyz, '_', a.index) AS quantity
FROM cte_t AS t
    ,LATERAL SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.abc, '_') a
WHERE productid != ''
```

giving

| ID | DATE | CATID | PRODUCTID | QUANTITY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | a | d | x |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | b | e | y |
| 1 | 2022-01-23 | c | f | w |